# Labeling features in given order in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, sorting, order

I want to sort the address numbers where would show only the bigger number and smaller value should be suppressed away.

I have used earlier `ORDER BY`-method when using PostGIS but now it isn't possible

How I can manage it using QGIS when labeling address numbers?

[image: example1]

Number 17 (blue) and 46 (red) should stay and 3 (blue) and 6 (red) suppressed

[image: Current situation]

The current situation where only the smaller address number exist, how to make this opposite?

Comment: How are the address numbers formatted? What do they look like? Can you provide a screenshot showing an example?

Comment: They are integer numbers

Comment: Do you mean _"in every situations where labels are overlapping"_ ?

Comment: yes, bigger number should win smaller

Comment: You're not answering my question ...

Comment: I tried also using Z-value. I inserted the address number value (toRight) into it. This should work but it dont. [![My GUI is in finnish, sorry!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsVdS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsVdS.png)

Comment: yes, I made both number visible because print screen -picture. This is current situation

Comment: Why do your labels seem to be located in 'corners' ... ? what do u label ? linestrings ? Aren't your labels located at the middle ?

Comment: They are lines. The address numbers need to placed in corners so I filter only using start and end points.

Comment: Can you share some data, to "play with it" ?

Answer (score -2):

Open the Layer Properties and go to Labels.

Set the labelling mode to Rule-Based Labelling:

[image]

Create a new rule and set the Filter to "NUMBER-FIELD" > 9

Set the labelling style as you normally would.

This will prevent any numbers under 10 from being displayed.

Comment: Is it the question asked ?

Comment: I assume this doesn't answer the question precisely, although rule-based labeling might be the right way to do it. The question seems to be about two or several labels residing in close proximity (i.e. in a corner of a building) and about eliminating the smaller one by value. So one should take into account label proximity first and then leave out label or labels which have a smaller value.

Comment: The rule will hide labels even when they aren't colliding ...

Comment: This seems like the best possible answer *given the currently available information*.  Unfortunately QGIS doesn't have a dedicated variable like `$currentlabelposition` that would make it possible to provide a generic solution. Any solution has to be custom-designed for the layer and data setup. @Mickeler needs to provide more information as requested (geometry type and current labeling settings) if they want a better answer.